# A fundamental question on relation between logic, formal system and mathematics.

Tags: logic

I was reading this book titled "Godel - A Life of Logic, by J.L Casti and  W.DePauli "
In pages 30-32 he mentions how a formal system is developed by using a set of symbols as 'axioms' and a set of transformation rules specified to transform from one axiom to another. A theorem is defined as to start with one axiom, convert the axiom using a series to transformation rules to obtain a last string. This last string is named a theorem.

Later, the authors mentions these manipulations and symbols in formal system are mapped to the kind of mathematical structure under consideration (Euclidean Geometry / Topology / Arithmetic).

How is this mapping from a formal system to mathematical structure performed? What are the constraints (with respect to to the transformations allowed in the formal system / the form of mathematical structure) that must be considered while mapping a specific formal system to a mathematical structure?
If possible suggest a reference where such a simple mapping is performed.

Comment: It sound like you have in mind the idea of interpretation of a formal system; it's the subject of model theory.  You can find an intro in logic textbooks, e.g., Enderton's *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*. The person who made the idea precise is Tarski; you might check out his own text, which, though a little dated, is a classic:  *Introduction to the Methodology of the Deductive Sciences*.